# How can I draw basic 3d with Vala?

Tags: development, thirdpartyapps

I'd like to make a visualizer in Vala for EOS.

The first chunk I'd like to achieve is drawing a rotating red cube.

I tried [valadoc](https://valadoc.org/) for "3d" and "gpu" but it only came up with non-contextualized functions; no useful docs.

**So where should I get started?**

What libraries should I know of?  Any links to docs or example projects?

Comment: Do these examples help? https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/OpenGLSamples; look here aswell https://github.com/Maia-Everett/valagl

Comment: These look like exactly the packages/examples I need to get my foot in the door and find a trail.